# change the element from the variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a dom which i am copying in variable.
I want to replace the particular element from the variable with another element.

```
<div id="parent">
  <section id="1"></section>
  <section id="2"></section>
  <section id="3"></section>
  <section id="4"></section>
</div>
```

This i have copied in variable. Now no relation with dom

I want to change it to

```
<div id="parent">
  <img id="5"></img>
  <section id="2"></section>
  <section id="3"></section>
  <section id="4"></section>
</div>
```

This is what i am trying

```
    var target = document.getElementById('parent');
    var wrap = document.createElement('div');
    wrap = wrap.appendChild(target.cloneNode(true));
```

Comment: you want to replace or copy and paste as a new DOM?

Comment: no dom manipulation i want, just change in variable which is carrying dom

Comment: You can't do that without DOM manipulation, because changing DOM is a DOM manipulation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var target = document.getElementById('parent');
    var wrap = document.createElement('div');
     wrap = wrap.appendChild(target.cloneNode(true));
    $(wrap).find("#1").html("<img id='5'></img>");
```

This works like a charm....without changing the dom

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('#parent').children().each(function(){
    var ids = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).replaceWith( '<img id="'+ids+'"/>' );
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gBBYd/)

Comment: no dom manipulation i want, just change in variable which is carrying dom